# Xamarin/Visual Studio Error - The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to run some source code that I downloaded from [here](https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2148)

This is essentially an app that will allow users to manage contacts and calendar appointments etc.

I am currently experiencing 5 errors, all seemingly related...

CS0103 - The name 'BigTed' does not exist in the current context.

I have downloaded the 'BTProgressHUD' component and tried including the line

```
using BigTed;
```

but it is not recognised.

I have attached my code below, I am not sure how to clear these errors.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using FiveMinuteMeeting.Shared.ViewModels;
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace FiveMinuteMeeting.iOS
{
partial class NewEventDateViewController : UIViewController
{
public NewEventViewModel ViewModel
{
  get;
  set;
}
    public NewEventDateViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }


public static DateTime NSDateToDateTime(NSDate date)
{
  DateTime reference = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(
      new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
  return reference.AddSeconds(date.SecondsSinceReferenceDate);
}

async partial void ButtonSchedule_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
  ViewModel.Date = NSDateToDateTime(DatePickerDate.Date);
  BigTed.BTProgressHUD.Show("Adding Event...");
  await ViewModel.AddEvent();
  BigTed.BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();
  NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
}
}
```

}

Comment: Was there a library? Have you added it to the references?

Comment: Thanks, the problem was due to the fact that the reference hadn't been included. Once i located the correct .dll it cleared the errors.

Thanks!

Comment: @Chris post that as answer and accept it.